# Webservice xsd:string in <[!CDATA[]]> instead of escaping special characters

Tags: java, web-services

There's a PHP SOAP webservice that needs to be fed with some objects that are created by my java service.

So, imagine I have something like this:

```
public class Foo {
    private String attribute;
    // getter/setter
}
...
   Foo foo = new Foo();

   foo.setAttribute("attr");
   String serializedFoo = getJsonSerializer().toJson(foo);

   // serialized foo {"attribute": "attr"}
   webService.addNewFoo(serializedFoo);
...
```

The problem is that the webservice is receiving the serialized foo like this:

```
{attribute: attr}
```

Sniffing my network I found that all my quotes are being scaped to *quot;*, like this.

```
{&quot;attribute&quot;:&quot;attr&quot;}
```

Is there a way that I can avoid that? I would like to send my string wrapped with *CDATA*. I don't want it to lose the quotes :/

I am using the

```
wsimport -keep -Xnocompile WSDL_LOCATION
```

to generate the client and manager for me to call the webservice. I am running the service in glassfish.

**EDIT**
I can't change the receiving end. I understand it should be able to parse the escaped quotes, but unfortunately I am able only to change the serialization from my side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CDATA is not the solution you are looking for.  the `&quot;` should work just fine for transmitting literal quote chars.  something on the receiving end is not correctly parsing the xml.

Comment: I understand that, but unfortunately I can't change the receiving end. Is there a way I can use the CDATA instead?

Comment: @RalfHoppen - do you have some indication that the receiving end handles CDATA correctly?

Comment: Yes, I tried it using firefox plugin, poster (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/poster/). It worked fine wrapped around CDATA.

Comment: @RalfHoppen - unfortunately, i doubt you're going to find a webservice library that writes CDATA.  CDATA is really just an xml "hack" which was supposed to make it easier to _hand_ write xml.  most xml libraries use normal escaping since it is much more robust than CDATA.  you may have to hand-craft your xml in order to achieve this.

Comment: Damned nuSOAP T_T Thanks for the help anyway.